# Need help in creating login/logout feature using GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-account

i am trying to add a login/logout feature to my web-app using UserService.
Here is the relevant code :

1) the Entry Point class :-

```
public class MarkerSimple implements EntryPoint {

    static LoginInfo loginInfo = null;

  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() { 

      System.out.println("onModuleLoad");

    LoginServiceAsync loginService = GWT.create(LoginService.class);
    loginService.login(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(), new AsyncCallback<LoginInfo>() {

      public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
          System.out.println("ERROR FETChinG Data");
      }

      public void onSuccess(LoginInfo result) {

          System.out.println(result);

        loginInfo = result;
        if(loginInfo.isLoggedIn()) {

          Constants.isLoggenIn = true;
        } else {

          Constants.isLoggenIn = false;
        }
        loadLogin();
      }
      });
  }

  private void loadLogin() {

      RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new GwtMaps());
  }
}
```

2) the Composite class :-

```
public class GwtMaps extends Composite {

    interface LoginWidgetURLBinder extends UiBinder <DockLayoutPanel, GwtMaps> {    }
    private static LoginWidgetURLBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LoginWidgetURLBinder.class);

    private GoogleMap map;
    int i=0;

    static Boolean isLoaded = false;

    @UiField
    Label label1;

    @UiField
    RadioButton myRadioAble;    

    @UiField
    SimpleLayoutPanel map_canvas;

    @UiField
    static Anchor signin;


    public GwtMaps() {

        System.out.println("GwtMaps");
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));     
        isLoaded = true;
        anchorHandler();
        LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(28.60753,77.03505);
        MapOptions myOptions = MapOptions.create();
        myOptions.setZoom(20.0);
        myOptions.setCenter(myLatLng);
        myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
        map = GoogleMap.create(map_canvas.getElement(), myOptions);
        map.addClickListener(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                i++;
                addMarker(event.getLatLng());
            }
        }); 



    }

      private void addMarker(LatLng location) {
            MarkerOptions newMarkerOpts = MarkerOptions.create();
            newMarkerOpts.setPosition(location);
            newMarkerOpts.setMap(map);
            newMarkerOpts.setTitle("Marker"+i);
            newMarkerOpts.setDraggable(true);
            newMarkerOpts.setAnimation(Animation.DROP);
            Marker.create(newMarkerOpts);
      }

      public static void anchorHandler() {

            if(Constants.isLoggenIn == false) {

                signin.setText("SignIn using Google");
                signin.setHref(MarkerSimple.loginInfo.getLoginUrl());
            } else {                

                signin.setText("SignOut");
                signin.setHref(MarkerSimple.loginInfo.getLogoutUrl());
            }           
      }
}
```

The problem is if the user was not logged in, even after logging in, following the Anchor, the data received from the RPC is not captured. Also i need a way to change the Anchor dynamically after performing a login or logout so that the same Anchor can perform a logout or login.
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think you can have a static @UiField as your signin is configured.
2. Do you have the url configured in the .ui.xml  because if not I do not see where you are doing a signIn.addClickHandler() and calling the login method.
3. I would move the login call to your view instead of having it in your module so that you can call it from the anchor with an addClickHandler or a @UiHandler("signin"). And make your module simply load the view.

   ```
   public class MarkerSimple implements EntryPoint {
       @Override
       public void onModuleLoad() {
           // Just this. 
           RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new GwtMaps());
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is their any way to pause the ClickEvent till the AsyncCallback returns ? event.wait() doesn't work. If i am able to pause it and then fire it once i know if login is required or logout, my work would be done !

Comment: There are two solutions to your problem. I would recommend initializing the text of the singin anchor to "Log in" and in the background during initialization make the call to check if the user is logged in. If they are you can then change the text to "Log out". This will happen so fast that the user will probably not notice the change. The other option is to move the code from your constructor to an init function and then your constructor can call to see if the user is logged in. After the check you can call initView which will call your initWidget and other initialization code.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I would just like to add, the login feature doesn't work correctly when running on local host, but it works as expected after deployment.
When running on local host i get a GWT module "name of app" needs to be recompiled error after signing in. 
Probably a harmless bug.

Comment: This error is typically caused by pointing the url to the compiled version of the app. Which should work if the app is compiled. But if you are using the development mode when running your app you probably want to use relative url paths so that the ?codesrvr=127.0.0.1:8888 or whatever the actual url is. If you do not have this appended to the url it will be pointing to your compiled version of the app. This is probably not desired behaviour when developing.